# CloudKit - How to perform Not Exists query?

Tags: cloudkit, not-exists

I want to perform a database query in CloudKit like in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid)
```

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.userid NOT IN(
    SELECT t2.userid
    FROM table2 t2);

or

SELECT t1.userid
FROM table1 t1
MINUS
SELECT t2.userid
FROM table2 t2;

Comment: Thanks but this is not possible in CloudKit. I want to find a way how it can still be done though...